# onmouseout is not working properly.Kindly help me to fix this

Tags: javascript

[image: My Code]

[image: My output]

I have tried to run the code but unfortunately it is not working.When i put the  pointer on the Click button it is not working properly.

Comment: Are there errors in your dev console (when you press F12 and head to "console")?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to put the button before the paragraph tag.

like this example:

```html
<button onmouseover="document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = Date()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = ''">Click</button>

<p id="c"></p>
```